# Regular expression to remove more than one continuous "--"

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

I have two requirements, first, I want to replace the "-" symbol in both beginning and end of the text with an empty value. Second, if there are any continuous "-" symbols they should be replaced with a single "-" symbol.

If possible please provide the code for both the requirements in a single pattern.

**CODE:**

```
//1.)
// replace more than 1 "-" in b
// Expected Output : -asdas-sadf-asdasd-ju

var a = "--asdas-sadf----asdasd---ju";
a = a.replace(/-{2,}/,"");
//alert(a);

//2.)
// remove last "-" and starting "-" from b that is "das-" - after das needs to be removed
// Expected output : welcome/asasdgrd/asd-ast-yret-das/456

var b = "-welcome/asasdgrd/asd-ast-yret-das-/456"
b = b.replace(/[-$]/,"");
//alert(b);
```

**Fiddler Link:**

http://jsfiddle.net/nj5j0yeq/1/

Comment: "*should be replaced with a single `-` symbol*" - you've named the solution already. Currently you are doing `.replace(…, "")`

Answer (score 1):

You need to use capturing groups.

```js
var s = "--asdas-sadf----asdasd---ju";
alert(s.replace(/^-+|-+$|(-)+/gm, "$1"));
```

Comment: Why does this not take the last trailing one? `var a = "--asdas-sadf----asdasd---ju------";
a = a.replace(/-{2,}/g,"-").replace(/^-+|-+$/,"");`

Comment: @mplungjan because you forget ot use global modifier in the second replace. `alert(a.replace(/-{2,}/g,"-").replace(/^-+|-+$/g,""));` . since the second replace need to do more than one match, that is one at the first and one at the last, you need to include that or otherwise only the first hyphen would be matched.

Answer (score 0):

```
^-+|-(?!.*?-)|(-){2,}
```

You can try this.Replace by `$1`.See demo.

https://regex101.com/r/jV9oV2/8

Answer (score 0):

You can check even time of `--` and can replace with odd `-`

```
var a = "--asdas-sadf----asdasd---ju";
var b= a.split("--").join("-");
var c = b;
var d = c.split("--").join("-");
console.log(d);
```

or `var res = str.split(/^-+$|(-)+/).join("");
    console.log(res);

`

Comment: Could you please elaborate more your answer adding a little more description about the solution you provide?